# Compare lists' position using a for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, position

If there are two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,1,3,5,4]
```

I want to use a `for` loop to compare them, I have to use `for` loop, so don't ask why, I was thinking:

```
for q,w in zip(a,b):
    if a[q] == a[w]:
        print "hi"
    else:
        print "bye"
```

The result I'm looking for is something like:

> bye bye hi bye bye

How can it achieve this result?

Comment: There's no reason to ask why, `for` loop is the best way of doing this

Answer (score 6):

It looks from your example that you're on the right track.  But I think you're misunderstanding what q and w represent.

In your example, q and w do not represent the index of the current elements of the collections you're looping through; they **are** the elements.  So for example, in the first iteration of that loop, q and w would be 1 and 2 respectively. Here is what you probably want:

```
for q,w in zip(a,b):
    if q == w:
        print "hi"
    else:
        print "bye"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [2,1,3,5,4]
>>> for q, w in zip(a, b):
        print "hi" if q == w else "bye"


bye
bye
hi
bye
bye
```